# VBA If Then statement to do stuff or end sub

Tags: excel, vba

I have trouble doing a simple code.  I want to add If Then statement, if the condition is met (a cell value is not 1 or 7), then do a block of codes, otherwise end the sub.  The block of codes include login to a website and 2 For Next loops.  Basically the macro is to run during weekdays and not run if it's Saturday or Sunday. Appreciate your help.

Here's a test code:

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer

'If cell E1 has a value of neither 1 or 7, Do stuff, otherwise End the Sub

If Cells(5, 1) <> 1 Or Cells(5, 1) <> 7 Then

    'Do stuff includes login and perform 2 For Next loops in my real code 
    For i = 1 To 3
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value * 2
    Next

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: change the `Or` to `And`

Comment: had you written *if cells(5,1)=1 or cells(5,1)=7 then exit sub* before your loop, that would solve the same issue.  it would remove the need for the end if block at the end of the code.  depending on the length of "do stuff" it might be cleaner in the long run this way

Comment: `Cells(5, 1)` is A5 not E1

Comment: Why check the sheet at all? VBA has a built-in function for checking the day of the week:  `If Weekday(Date, vbMonday) > 5 Then`

Comment: Thanks for all the tips.  I realize I have the cell wrong as A5 and I will look into vba function for checking on day of the week... thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Integer

    'If cell E1 has a value of neither 1 or 7, Do stuff, otherwise End the Sub

    If Cells(5, 1) = 1 Or Cells(5, 1) = 7 Then
    Else
        'Do stuff includes login and perform 2 For Next loops in my real code
        For i = 1 To 3
            Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value * 2
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally able to do achieve what I want.  I created a new sub that check the day of the week and if it's Saturday or Sunday Then Exit Sub, Else call the original sub that I have and it works great.  However as Comintern suggested, I will look into the VBA function of checking date instead of using the spreadsheet.  Thanks to all.